# MYSQL Trigger to correct entries

Tags: mysql, triggers, integer

I have a mysql table that is updated through a web page.  Some columns are formatted as integer.  There will be a mysql error if you try to enter "", " ", or any string that cannot be rounded to integer automatically.  Instead of editing my PHP to handle these corrections, I would like to make a trigger BEFORE UPDATE on this table that sets the field value to zero if it is an incorrect integer value.  In another stack overflow post I found that you could test for integer value using `ceil(field) = field`.  Here is the create trigger syntax:

```
delimiter|
create trigger before_folding_update before update on daily_folding_report
for each row
begin
if ceil(new.jobnum) != new.jobnum then
  set new.jobnum = 0;
end if;
end|
```

If I put do:

```
update daily_folding_report set jobnum = 'a'
```

I still get the error: `Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'jobnum' at row 1.`  Does anyone else know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, all value checks are done before the triggers. Why aren't you just doing this in your PHP code?

Comment: Just a little experiment.  I often have multiple programs accessing the same table. I always like a more robust solution.  Yes I will alter my PHP code no doubt if this trigger method is impossible.

Comment: Well, MySQL will expect `new.jobnum` to be an integer before it even starts the trigger, to avoid the trigger going crazy because it has something it shouldn't ever have.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying, however I have made a trigger before that will give a value to a primary key if one isn't given in the insert query.  This is when I have a special primary key field that isn't auto-incrementing.

Comment: True, but the difference is that `auto_increment` is something that's done **ON** insert, while your trigger is executed **BEFORE** insert. This will allow you to change it. The order of handling events in MySQL is something like `query interpretation -> type checks -> trigger (before) -> handle special keys such as auto_increment -> update -> trigger (after) -> done`